# How do I tell how many VPP downloads my app has had?

Tags: itunes, apple-vpp

I'm not seeing anything about VPP in my App Analytics or Sales and Trends.  Is there a way to see how many VPP installs there have been?  I can kind of guess based on spikes in activity, but if there were a way to know for sure, that would be excellent.  Please advise.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I am also interested in this.